# Iterative Closest Point Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, iteration, registration, point, closest

I'm having an issue trying to understand a key part of the algorithm. Currently I'm doing the following in my algorithm.

- Associating points (brute force for now)
- Using SVD to find optimal rotation and translation for reference to target.
- Applying the rotation and translation to the current reference data set.
- Updating the data set and then start over.

I'm confused on how you keep track of the "`total`" transformation and "`total`" rotation. Currently I just keep track of the old rotation and multiply this by the new 'optimal' rotation to get the current total rotation. In other words `rotation(i) = newRot * rotation (i-1)`.

For translation I do

`translation(i) = (newRot*translation(i-1)) + newTrans`.

Is this incorrect? I believe it is because my `RMSE` is increasing every loop, not decreasing; so my ICP algorithm isn't converging.

Comment: I'm not certain I 100% follow everything, but you need to be careful about rotation; rotation about the origin has intuitive behavior, but applying a rotation on a translated point does not (and you usually don't intend to treat the problem as so); so at least in graphics it's common to effectively translate to the origin, rotate, and translate back.

Comment: A better choice of tags will give you a better chance to get a good answer. `registration` seems to be about user login, and `point` doesn't say much. You're expecting readers to know what SVD, RMSE and ICP are, maybe those would be better tags?

Comment: You're probably right. I'll need to post this somewhere else. Registration refers to registering one set of 3D points with another set of 3D points. This can also be extended to 2D. You can use an ICP (Iterative Closest Point) to stitch multiple images together to make a panoramic image. You can also use it go register the coordinate system of some device with that of a CT scanner so you can super impose another image ontop of the CT scan. This last application is what I'm aiming to do but I want to develop it myself

Comment: New question post is here: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21609/iterative-closest-point-algorithm

Comment: What I did, and it may not be the most efficient, is after you do all of the iterations to find the matched points. Just re-run the original input points to the matched pairs and you will get the final transformation matrix instead of trying to compound the transforms through the iterations.